# Rounding a datetime value down to the nearest half hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to round a datetime2 value down to the nearest half hour. For example '10/17/2013 12:10:00.123' would round down to '10/17/2013 12:00:00.0' And '10/17/2013 12:34:17.123' would round down to 10/17/2013 12:30:00.0'. My first thought was to create a UDF which would break the date and time apart and do it that way. However, I'm wondering if something like this can be done in a single T-SQL statement?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and the data type of the column is a dateTime2 (which cannot be converted to a float!!)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer by Ian is good, but it contains an unnecessary conversion. I suggest

```
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST([columnname] AS float) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) FROM [tableName]
```

If you want to round to the nearest half-hour instead of always rounding down, use

```
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CAST([columnname] AS float) * 48.0,0)/48.0) FROM [tableName]
```

Comment: This will not work. My column is a dateTime2 and you cannot convert these to a float.

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, ROUND(CONVERT(float,CONVERT(datetime,[columnname])) * 48.0,0,1)/48.0) FROM [tableName]` -- unless you are using the extended date range provided by datetime2, of course.

Comment: BTW, what does the value of 48 represent?

Comment: When you convert a datetime to float, the part before the decimal point represents the number of days and the part after the decimal point is the time (in fraction of the day). Thus, if you multiply with 24, you get the number of hours, multiplying with 1440 would get you the minutes etc.

Comment: I see, sow 48 gets you half hours (30 minutes). Nice.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I took it as template, but had to round up (not down); therefore I changed your statement to `SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, CEILING(CAST([columnname] AS float) * 48.0)/48.0) FROM [tableName]`. This should be correct, right? If so, there should be no difference to using FLOOR in your solution. Feel free to correct me, if I missed something (performance?).

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
declare @d datetime = '2013-05-06 12:29.123'
select 
case 
    when datepart(minute, @d) < 30 then cast(dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute,@d)-datepart(second,@d), @d) as smalldatetime)
    when datepart(minute, @d) >= 30 then cast(dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute,@d)-datepart(second,@d)+30, @d) as smalldatetime)
end
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. If the datetime value contains seconds, the seconds are retained. This is not what I want.

Comment: Then just extract and then subtract the seconds, to get 0?  (Different Andrew, for the record...)

Comment: Ok, I edited my original answer and removed the seconds and cast to smalldatetime to ensure that the milliseconds don't come into play

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
update t set
  d = dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,'19000101',d)/30*30,'19000101');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(floor(cast(
    cast('10/17/2013 12:34:00' as datetime) 
as float(53)) * 48) / 48 as datetime)
```

**EDIT**

Works better if you use smalldatetime to avoid the extra precision

```
select cast(floor(cast(
    cast('2012-01-02 11:33:14.097' as smalldatetime) 
as float(53)) * 48) / 48 as smalldatetime)
```

Comment: This does not work. '2012-01-02 11:33:14.097' gets converted to '2012-01-02 11:29:59.997'

Comment: @Hosea146 Found that smalldatetime works better, as demonstrated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach that I used when I needed to round down to the nearest 5 minute interval.  There is probably a way to simplify this further, but at least this got me what I needed.

```
DECLARE @now datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT @now as cur_datetime, DATEADD(MINUTE, -(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DATEADD(HOUR,DATEDIFF(HOUR,0,@now), 0),DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,@now), 0)) % 5), DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,@now), 0)) as round_down_to_nearest_5_minute_mark
```

Answer (score 0):

@Twinkles's answer works well in SQL server to round to closest half an hour.

However, in development, strongly recommend use FLOOR to round to ***last half an hour***.

`SELECT CONVERT(datetime, FLOOR(CAST([columnname] AS float) * 48.0)/48.0) FROM [tableName]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DATETIME2FROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetime2fromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to reconstruct the date. To round the minutes *down* to 30 minute intervals use the formula `minutes intdiv 30 * 30`

```sql
SELECT
    dt2,
    DATETIME2FROMPARTS(
        DATEPART(year, dt2),
        DATEPART(month, dt2),
        DATEPART(day, dt2),
        DATEPART(hour, dt2),
        DATEPART(minute, dt2) / 30 * 30,
        0,
        0,
        0
    )
FROM (VALUES
    -- generic datetime2
    (SYSDATETIME()),
    -- 30 minute boundary
    ('2001-01-01 00:29:59.9999999'),
    ('2001-01-01 00:30:00.0000000'),
    ('2001-01-01 00:30:00.0000001'),
    -- min and max date
    ('0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'),
    ('9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999')
) AS v(dt2)
```