# T- SQL Split time in half hour intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `calls` that shows every call for every employee and looks like this:

| date | employee | call_pick_up_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-08 | 12345 | 2021-10-08 08:13:26 |
| 2021-10-08 | 123456 | 2021-10-08 08:16:42 |

Now I want to show the call **count** for each employee for **every 30 minutes** interval:

| interval | employee | call_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08:00 | 12345 | 4 |
| 08:00 | 123456 | 7 |
| 08:30 | 12345 | 5 |
| 08:30 | 123456 | 3 |

The considered period is `08:00 - 08:30 / 08:30 -09:00` and so on.

Is there an easy way to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your 30 minute windows would need to be more like 08:00-08:29 | 08:30-08:59 | 09:00-09:29 etc.
With your current 'considered period' logic you run the risk of inflating the number of calls, because a call could possibly exist in both 30 minute windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounding a datetime value down to the nearest half hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427485/rounding-a-datetime-value-down-to-the-nearest-half-hour)

Comment: Put that inside `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` then group by it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I like to round datetime values to the nearest *n*-minute interval is to take advantage of SQL Server's integer math behavior. If you take the difference in minutes between midnight and the time in question, then divide by *n* and then multiply by *n*, it gets rid of any remainder. So to round right now down to the previous 30-minute interval:

```
DECLARE @now   datetime = GETDATE();
DECLARE @today datetime = CONVERT(date, @now);

SELECT DATEADD
(
  MINUTE, 
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @today, @now)/30*30,
  @today
);
```

We can apply this to your query by taking your source table and using `CROSS APPLY` as Charlie suggested and apply that same calculation to your source values (you have to do a little more conversion inline because you don't have nice, static variables to use):

```
DECLARE @WindowSizeInMinutes smallint = 30;

SELECT x.interval, c.employee, call_count = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Calls AS c
CROSS APPLY 
(
  VALUES 
  (
    DATEADD
    (
      MINUTE, 
      DATEDIFF
      (
        MINUTE, 
        CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, call_pick_up_time)), 
        call_pick_up_time
      ) / @WindowSizeInMinutes * @WindowSizeInMinutes,
      CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, call_pick_up_time))
    )
  )
) AS x(interval)
-- WHERE c.something something
GROUP BY c.employee, x.interval;
```

If there is an index on `call_pick_up_time` you were hoping to use, that's out the window.

Another approach that could make use of an index is to pre-determine all the *possible* 30-minute windows in the range you're after, and then inner join to those:

```
DECLARE @WindowSizeInMinutes smallint = 30,
        @min_date datetime = '20211001', 
        @max_date datetime = '20211014';
    
;WITH n(n) AS
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL 
  SELECT n + 1
    FROM n WHERE n <= 24*60/@WindowSizeInMinutes
),
days(d) AS
(
  SELECT @min_date UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d)
    FROM days WHERE d < @max_date
),
intervals AS 
(
  SELECT interval_start = DATEADD(MINUTE, n*@WindowSizeInMinutes, d),
         interval_end   = DATEADD(MINUTE, (n+1)*@WindowSizeInMinutes, d)
    FROM n CROSS JOIN days
)
SELECT interval = i.interval_start, 
   c.employee, 
   call_count = COUNT(c.employee)
FROM intervals AS i
INNER JOIN dbo.Calls AS c
   ON c.call_pick_up_time >= i.interval_start
  AND c.call_pick_up_time <  i.interval_end
GROUP BY c.employee, i.interval_start;
```

While more complicated, one nice thing about this approach is if you want to show slots for windows where no employees had calls, you could just change the join to an inner join, and if you wanted a slot for each employee, you could just add a CTE with the list of employees and cross join to that.

- Both examples on [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=deae281974a6d3dbd2f3ccfe901ab320)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great approach. I tried many things from other similar questions, but had no luck. The first solution shows already the result i wanted. I will try the second one too, because i like the idea of showing the slots fpr windows where no employees had calls. Thanks!